# WebGL - trying to add thickness to a dynamically generated 3D model (waterproofing for printing)

Tags: javascript, webgl, 3d-model

I am looking for some inputs on, how I can add wall thickness to a 3D model without using softwares like blender.

I am having a 3D model built dynamically using vertices and indexes to build the wall. Now I need to take this model for printing. I need to add wall thickness before I take it for printing.

Is there any library which does that, or a document which explains how to do it?

My thought (which wont work in every case):
If it is a cylinder model, then we can just increase the radius of it and just join the bigger and the smaller cylinders to get a wall thickness. But what if we have a asymmetrical object? this technique wont work here.